# How do I delete columns in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(vin, make, model, year, category)
```

*I would like to delete/remove columns, "year" and "category", and put them in a new view*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` to get all the columns except the 'year' and 'category'.

```
 df1 <- df[setdiff(colnames(df), c('year', 'category'))]
 df1
 #  vin make model
 #1   1    A     D
 #2   2    B     E
 #3   3    C     F
```

Including the comments from @Frank and @Ben Bolker.

We can assign the columns to NULL

```
  df$year <- NULL
  df$category <- NULL
```

Or use `subset` from `base R` or `select` from `dplyr`

```
  subset(df, select=-c(year, category))
  library(dplyr)
  select(df, -year, -category)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(vin=1:3, make=LETTERS[1:3], model=LETTERS[4:6],
           year=1991:1993, category= paste0('GR', 1:3))
```

Comment: Assigning NULL to each also works, I guess because data.frames are lists  of (pointers to) vectors: `df$year <- NULL; df$category <- NULL`

Comment: or, conveniently (with the known [caveats about using subset()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)), use `subset(df,select=-c(year,category))` or `dplyr::select(df,-c(year,category))`